# Firebase: Can I specify my app client version before connecting?

Tags: firebase

I'm wondering if it is possible to specify my app's version number before initializing firebase on it, in order to prevent read/writes from old clients (or at least make that read/writing conditional).

Sometimes I introduce a breaking change to my API and don't want old clients to foul my database.